# Managing a company account on PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

A **company** wants to publish FOSS Python packages on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/), e.g. they want to delegate the right to upload packages on their behalf to some employees.

It seems that an account in PyPi is always tied to a single person, e.g. the company would have to share the username/password with each individual that should be allowed to upload packages on the company's behalf. This is not very useful, especially when employees leave the company as they would still know the credentials for that single, shared account.

Is there some kind of solution that allows to manage PyPi users under a company account's umbrella so that a manager can add/delete users from the company account -- similar to a [GitHub organization](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-organizations)?

Comment: The [FAQ](https://pypi.org/help/#collaborator-roles) says you can add "collaborators."

Comment: or you can also use API token: https://pypi.org/help/#apitoken to upload the package

Comment: The question must be directed to PyPA… Oh, you've already asked: https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/8869 Nice! The question could be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Not currently but this feature is planned: https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/201